# Offline Maps for C++ Desktop Application

Tags: openstreetmap

Im trying to find an opensource API to to embedded offline maps in a C++ application wich graphics is make with Qt 5.7 library.

The aim is to show some colored  streets according certain requirements in a fixed area (maximum one city at time) so it would be great if it is lighter that's mean a minimal amount of data.

I read some about this and found that Openstreetmap is a good option,but i dont have any experience with maps.

Thanks if you can give me any direction

Comment: Maybe you find an answer at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering. libosmscout and Mapbox Qt SDK sound promising.

Comment: Mapbox support team just told me “we don't currently support the Windows platform”. And Libosmscout support team “Sadly the combination MinGW+CMake is broken since some time”

Comment: Then maybe just go for Leaflet or OpenLayers and display a (possibly local) webpage inside your application?